# Angularjs - Reload page even if same url

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, reload, url-parameters

I'm using Angularjs 1.3, my project has 2 submenus:

1. href="/submenu"
2. href="/submenu?page=1"

When I am on submenu page and clicks on second url, the page is not reloading, it simply update the url, but does nothing. I have written the code when user lands on second url with that query parameter.

I don't want to force reload the page with 
`window.location.reload();`, because it will empty the $rootscope.

I have one solution, by redefining url code with Angular ui-router but it is time consuming since redefining will break the major features. I am looking for quick fix right now.

Comment: Use ng-view to show the page on the current page it self.

Comment: Have you configured the routes properly ? If not try this article https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

Comment: Yeah, I have configured it properly, that is not an issue. This is angular's behavior, it does not reload the page, if we click on link which has same url as current page. I have fixed my problem and answered it below.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('?page=1','_self');">...</a>
```

Check if $rootscope is empty, to make it sure.

Answer (score 0):

I quick fixed it. There was a guy who commented but, removed it now. He said I should call the function with data to update the view, instead of redirecting, and I did that.

But in my case, menu is out of that page's controller scope, I used vanilla js for the link redirection (need to perform some action before redirecting).
So in order to call the controller's function, I checked if I am on the same page, if yes, then grab the angular scope from the page, in order to get all the functions defined in that controller, using:

```
angular.element($('#someId')).scope();
```

SomeID should be set on the element on which ng-controller is defined. It gave me all the functions defined in that controller's scope. Then I just called the function and page gets updated, without reloading, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use ***target="_self"***:

1. href="/submenu"  target="_self"
2. href="/submenu?page=1"  target="_self"